# How can I detect when source of iframe is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to detect when user clicks a link in `iframe` and changes the source of `iframe`, because I want to resize it. Also I use jQuery. What is the best way to detect this?

Actually I need something like this (this example is in jQuery, it does not work, I imagined this)

```
$('#iframe').live('load', function(){ alert('src is changed')});
```

Comment: Is the iframe pointing at the same domain, or another one?

Comment: same domain but , maybe another subdomain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to use the `onLoad` event, as in the following example:

```
<iframe src="/test.html" onLoad="alert(this.contentWindow.location);"></iframe>
```

The alert will pop-up whenever the location within the iframe changes. It works in all modern browsers, but may not work in some very older browsers like IE5 and early Opera. ([Source](http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/3126/Telling-when-an-iframe-is-done-loading))

Note that you will not be able to access the `contentWindow.location` if the iframe is in a different domain or sub-domain, but the `onLoad` event will still fire.

Comment: Yes, it will. Is that a problem?

Comment: yes I guess `How can I detect when ` **source** ` of iframe is changed?`

Comment: @Reigel: If the iframe is pointing to a page within the same domain, the OP can check `this.contentWindow.location` to see if the iframe is pointing to a new `scr`. If the iframe is refreshed, the `onLoad` will still fire, but `this.contentWindow.location` will be set to the same value as before. This should be very easy to check.

Comment: this does not work... ff says permission denied when executed

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an exactly clean solution, but it will work: you can create a timer that periodically checks if the iframe source has changed.

```
var prevSrc = '';
function check() {
  var curSrc = $('#iframe').attr('src');
  if (curSrc != prevSrc) {
    // source has changed; do something
    prevSrc = curSrc;
  }
}

window.setInterval(check, 1000); // 1 sec - this can be anything you want
```

Comment: @casablanca: Do you know if this works even when the iframe navigates to a new page from a link within the iframe itself?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo No it will not because the 'src' won't change.

Comment: NB:`curSrc != prevSrc` will be true on the first firing as `prevSrc` will be `null` vs the iframe src.

Comment: @casablanca, @Ozaki: I think the OP is asking for an event that is fired when a user navigates from within the iframe: `"I want to detect when user clicks a link in iframe"`.

Comment: @stormdrain: Indeed. If that's not needed, just set `prevSrc` to the original source.

@Daniel: I guess you're right, which leads to your solution of using `contentWindow.location` instead of `src`.

Comment: @casablanca: technically this script won't work the way you intended anyway. The attr will always return the same thing (the iframe src) unless the iframe has a script that updates the iframe src attribute.

Comment: Yes, I did mention in my previous comment that Daniel's solution is correct.