# Refresh entrire page after clicking/submitting into an iframe

Tags: html, css, redirect, iframe, refresh

```
<iframe width="920px" height="500px" style="border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;" src="http://login.uid.me/?site=dinterncup-thc&ref=http://interncup-thc.ucoz.com/" onclick="refreshIframe();"></iframe>
```

I would like that **AFTER** refreshing the page inside the iframe, to **refresh** OR **redirect** the **WHOLE** page. How can i do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have function that handles what happens when the form gets submitted?

Comment: i just want that after the iframe content gets refreshed, the main website do the same

Comment: OK. Here is a similar question that addresses this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162993/how-can-i-detect-when-source-of-iframe-is-changed

Comment: <iframe src="/test.html" onLoad="alert(this.contentWindow.location);"></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

From the iframe, you can modify the url of the parent window. Add this to your refreshIframe function:

```
parent.location.href="yourNewURL";
```

This assumes that the iframe and its parent are in the same domain.

Comment: you mean like this? onclick="refreshIframe(); parent.location.href="http://interncup-thc.ucoz.com/";" because it's not working:( Here is the link for website: http://interncup-thc.ucoz.com/index/login/0-5 i just want to refresh the page or redirect it to homepage once it has logged in, after the iframe content gets refreshed, the main website do the same

Comment: I meant to add the code inside your refreshIframe function, but this should work too. In this case use single quotes! parent.location.href='http://interncup-thc.ucoz.com/'

Comment: so, i can't refresh the main page after the page from inside the iframe refreshes unless they are both on the same domain??

Comment: Correct (unless you can implement communication between both pages, like postMessage). For different domains, the parent only sees the iframe attributes (src, onload for example).

Comment: well, thanks i guess. this cross-domain thing is very stressfull